# Eclipse Kepler SR2 User Operation is Waiting Even without any tasks displayed

Tags: java, eclipse

"The user operation is waiting for background work to complete."

I have searched and read for many of the solutions to this problem, yet I am still experiencing issues with long blocking on Save (sometimes up to a minute) on Kepler SR2 Build id = 20140224-0627. (This is on Windows 7 with 16GB RAM). What's interesting is that the Progress menu even shows "No operations to display at this time."

Settings:

1. I have Build Automatically disabled.
2. I have Save automatically before build enabled (Although I have tried it with the option disabled as well)

I have tried starting eclipse with -clean option enabled, but to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea why it would block even with out anything showing in the Progress window, and nothing in the Modal besides "Save"? I have noticed that when this occurs the CPU usage in Task Manager for java is much higher than normal.

Wondering if there is anything I can do before resorting to getting a new workspace or fresh install of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose such a problem, enable the display of system tasks by opening the "view menu" of the progress view (click the downward arrow symbol), click "Preferences" and toggle "Show sleeping and system operations" - or take a thread dump of the eclipse process, and look at what the worker threads are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer (and you probably moved on :p), but Eclipse does a bunch of stuff behind the scenes for many operations. Most importantly, there are many builders that can be invoked (Project Settings -> Builders). Not sure which language you are using, but with CDT for C++, there are also a bunch of parsers and syntax checkers that get invoked.

You could try disabling some of them until this problem goes away. This solved an infinite rebuild loop for me.